# what is covering the grout in my shower and how do I repair it?

Tags: shower, tile, grout

I recently moved and the bathroom (and shower) floor is tile with large grout lines between it. In the shower there is signs of wear on the grout and it appears it was sealed somehow and the sealant is wearing away. How do I identify and repair this? Pictures below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the large uneven grout lines are a "look", done intentionally.   IDk what that light  stuff is that was applied over your grout and is now peeling.  That is obviously failing.  It's not obvious from your picture whether the actual grout underneath is failing, or why the coating was applied.    Can you answer any of these questions or at least provide clear photos of the original grout failures in a couple of places?   My approach would be to scrape off all the coating if there's nothing wrong with the grout, or to completely or partially regrout if there is.

Comment: Ah, yes - I see some 1970's "designer" taking the tile crew out to drink their lunch just before shower tiling commences, to achieve this look, deliberately. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

Identify: No practical means to do so. Also no need.

Repair: Cut this mess out with a grout saw and regrout.

Repair option 2: Remove and retile (since the tiling looks very sloppy, with grout line widths all over the map, which will make grout sawing *extra fun!*)

Comment: Regarding the repair, I'm mostly interested in if the top layer has some function other than aesthetic that I need to preserve.